# Approving embedded Youtube videos

Tags: youtube

I'm creating an HTML page that embeds youtube videos that have been internally approved. A problem that can occur is if the author of the approved video decides to change the approved video to another video that have not been approved. Is there a way that I can embed a youtube video into a page and have it disabled if the author of that video decides to change the video?